# JDL pattern is not correct in Java @Pattern

Tags: jhipster

When I applied pattern in `JDL`, the generated entity classes has `@Pattern`annotation, but the value for that annotation is not the exact pattern which applied in `JDL`.

For example, if I've defined patterns as 
 `pattern('/[^\\s]+.*[^\\s]+/')` 
and in java 
it reflects as 
`@Pattern(regexp = "[^\\\\s]+.*[^\\\\s]+")`

If you noticed in java class, there are 4 (slash) which indeed should be 2 only. Because of this functionality is getting failed.

Comment: Correction to question. java class pattern is @Pattern(regexp = "[^\\\\s]+.*[^\\\\s]+")

Comment: So what is your question? It looks more like a bug report to me.

Comment: in simple words the pattern which provides in jdl for white space is not reflect as it is in java class. //(2 slashesh) gets replace in java class by ////(4 slashesh). Validation fails because of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to use regex control characters in your pattern, which do *not* need to be doubled up in your JDL: see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields, especially the part under "Regular Expressions" where it says: "/.../ the pattern is declared inside two slashes... \ anti-slashes needn’t be escaped"

So it's acting correctly. Since you have double-backslants in your JDL, Java is correctly interpreting it with quadruple-backslants. Your solution is just to use single backslants in your JDL, as per the documentation.